# convert mongodb to postgres in rails

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 projects, 1 is rails project containing apis for Mobile application which database is in MongoDB and on opposite side other project is in spree which database is in  postgres, So how might I synchronize both the databases? I want to make entries in both databases but at the same time. If rails api project get any entry in postgres database so, it would also make same entry into mongodb database.

Comment: https://www.torodb.com/

Comment: If you're aiming for two-way direction of replication (mongodb to postgres, and postgres to mongodb) you would have to write a custom code for it. Your custom code should deal with how you would like to merge any conflicts found.